# Can we calculate accuracy of hough line transform for line segmentation in matlab?

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, hough-transform

I tried matlab code example for hough line transform and modified threshold value, and got different result. i want to know how can i calculate error in hough line transform.

Comment: What do you mean by “error”? First start with a formal definition. Once you have that, you can sefine a metric that captures the error.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So we only can see it by picture? not by number? for example, measure circumference or perimeter object before and after line segmentation

Comment: I did not say that. You can measure error in many different ways. But first you need to define what “error” means. Distance between true line and detected line? Fraction of true lines detected? Number of false line detected? Once you define exactly and precisely what you want to quantify, you’ll likely be able to set up an experiment to quantify it.